# Distinct items on property from 2 lists

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I got a `Person` class that looks like this:

```
Person1: Id=1, Name="Test1"
Person2: Id=2, Name="Test2"
Person3: Id=3, Name="Test3"
```

And an `IEnumerable<int>` with unique `Person` id's:

```
var personIds = new PersonRepository().GetAll().Select(x => x.Id);
```

I need a list of `Person` where the id's are not present in the `IEnumerable<int>`.

This is one of my many tries:

```
from n in personIds 
from x in Person
where x.Id != n
select x;
```

I just keep getting everything back, including the Id's that are present in the `personIds`.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you call to get the the list of all `Person`s, does `Get` have another overload?

Comment: No, it just gets all persons. Should be - by the way - GetAll(). Typo. But Cuong Le got me into the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var results = Persons.Where(p => !personIds.Contains(p.Id));
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! I've tried Contains as well, but in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

```
from n in Persons 
where !Persons.Any(c=>personIds.Contains(c.Id));
select n
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

It should be something like,

```
var allButExclusions =
    PersonRepository.GetAll().Where(p => !exclusions.Contains(p.Id));
```

but, its not obvious how you derive the list of all `Person`s or the list of `Id`s to exclude.

Comment: It returns an IEnumerable of all persons.